# Ascending order in controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[image]

In this picture, we can see the "**cockNoM**" has been displayed. But the problem is they are not in order. **My target is to display them in order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6**. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much

Controller:

```
function asdasdas(){
            $entry= $this->repo->entryfetch();
            
            
            
            $data='<table>
    <thead><tr><th>NO. ENTRY NAME</th><th>WB</th><th>LB</th><th>WT</th><th>NO #</th><th>ENTRY NAME</th><th>WB</th><th>LB</th><th>WT</th><th>Diff</th></tr></thead>';
          
            
            foreach($entry as $entry){
                
                $match= $this->repo->matchfetch($entry->handlerID);
                
                $data.='<thead><tr><th><hr>'.$entry->handlerID.'&nbsp;'.$entry->entryName.'</th> ';
     
             
                
                foreach($match as $match){
                    
                    $diff = $match->weightM - $match->weightW;
                    
                    if($match->handlerIDM === $entry->handlerID){
                        $name=$match->handlertestW;
                        $cock=$match->cockNoM;
                    }else{
                        
                        $name=$match->handlerM;
                        $cock=$match->cockNoW;
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    $data.='<tbody><tr><td>'.$cock.'</td><td>'.$match->wingBandM.'</td><td>'.$match->legBandM.'</td><td>'.$match->weightM.'</td><td>'.$match->handlerIDW.'</td><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$match->wingBandW.'</td><td>'.$match->legBandW.'</td><td>'.$match->weightW.'</td><td>'.$diff.'</td>';
               
                    $data.='<td></td></tr></tbody>';
    //             
                }
               
                
            }
            
            $data .='<table>';
          
            echo $data;
            
        }
```

Comment: What is the `cockNoM` in your image? I cannot get it

Comment: It is a fetched data that contains 1,2,3,4,5,6 etfc. The count that I need to do an ascending order. Sorry for making you confuse. Thank you.